# Assign a map area (coordinates) - to text that shows when hovering

Tags: html, css

So I found out how to code text so it shows when hovering an image, but I can't seem to make it work with a map.

Here is the HTML.

```
<a>
    <img src="http://i621.photobucket.com/albums/tt296/viktorvnh/deskone_zpswpfj5mrc.jpg" usemap="#Map"/>

    <map name="Map" id="Map">
         <area shape="rect" coords="374,414,624,570" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"/>
    </map>
</a>
```

The map area is assigned to a modal, and I would also like to assign it to a text that shows up when hovering...

... using this CSS-script:

```
  a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.caption {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    color: #f90;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.1em;
}
a:hover .caption {
    display: block;
}
```